# Traversing which object type is the fastest in java

Tags: java, collections

I was wondering which Java collection types are traversed fastest. Collections I am most interested in are...

1. array
2. LinkedList
3. Queue
4. PriorityLinkedList
5. HashMap

Comment: What exactly do you have to do?

Comment: It depends on what you are using them for.

Comment: May I ask if I has a Collection contains n elements, I want to pick out all possible pairs of elements in this Collection. SO it would be n(n-1)/2 pair. Which one that I can use for fastest time execute .

Answer (score 2):

Actually among concrete classes of Collection interface , traversing will be fast through **array**. Its because as you know it traverse with the index of the element.Since it follows the index pattern so,traversing through index it makes our traversing fast. Why not others? Let me explain one by one..

1.**LinkedList** : LinkedList follows the insertion order.If you traverse the data and     searching for elements,for every element it will search from beginning. So traversing becomes slow.

2.**Queue** : LinkedList and PriorityQueue are two concrete classes of Queue. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.It's not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()). So it becomes useless for traversing provided if you traverse without sorting it explicitly.

3.**HashMap**: If you use Map instead of Collection , traversing is not guaranteed here because it works on hashcode of the key element. So here again traversing becomes useless. You can directly search the element by providing key-value of the element.

4.**PriorityLinkedList**: This class does not exist in Java APIs.

Comment: I need to design some component in my project accordingly